# How difficult is it to build a website in Sitecore CMS

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I have got one project where I need to build a site in Sitecore CMS.
I have never used that CMS.

I want to know that if my programming skills are good because I don't know ASP or ASP.net but do know PHP.

The sites are simple html pages with no logins and processing.

Can I do it few weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a PHP person when my company switched to Sitecore, although we had an ASP.net developer.

99% of what is done in Sitecore is achieved without any .net programming requirement. A website consists of data templates, which are defined in the Sitecore desktop environment (much like Windows, but in a browser). Data templates define the fields that each type of page has, the workflow it is in and other content-centric things. Renders are then attached to the template - these are xslt files which take the data provided by the data template and format it into (x)html.

I'd recommend getting enrolled on the Sitecore Developer Training - this is a one day course which will get you fully set up and ready to start building.

http://www.sitecore.net/en/Training.aspx

Sitecore v6 is easier to build with than v5. There's also SDN (sdn.sitecore.net) which has a large amount of documentation and examples.

Also, as Sitecore is only available through Sitecore Partners, you should have access to a knowledgeable Sitecore Professional.

Comment: Though XSL is an option with Sitecore, you will get significant performance benefit from using ASP.NET to output your content. You might try a little ASP.NET development to see the learning curve. Always good to diversify your skills anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's real easy.

http://www.sitecore.net/en/Products/Sitecore-CMS.aspx

> **Sitecore Makes it Effortless to Create Content and Experience Rich Websites**
>
> Sitecore helps you achieve your business goals such as increasing sales and search engine visibility, while being straightforward to integrate and administer. Sitecore lets you deliver sites that are highly scalable, robust and secure, and is built to simplify your life, automate your processes, and let you deliver results faster.

Seriously, this question can't be answered as is.  Sitecore CMS can be used by business users with no dev experience and it can be used by developers to do more complicated things.  How complicated it is to use Sitecore depends entirely on what exactly you're trying to do.  It might be easy, it might be complicated, but without more details it's impossible to know.

Comment: thanks for the info . ACtually i have never done ASP or ASP.NET. I am PHP person and have been using JOOMLA as main CSS. The site just have  5 navigation tabs and then pages linked to that . That's it. I could built those in php in 2 days. But as i don't now .net and sitecore so i was not able to quote how much time its going to take